# How to make the setup.exe from a VS2010 Setup Project ask for Admin Privileges?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer, uac, setup-deployment

I have a problem which I guessed would be really simple to solve... but duh.

I'm deploying a .NET application with VS2010. I have a C# Windows Forms project and a Deployment Project. I need the installer to run with admin privileges because the app is installed for all users and an entry to the registry is made.

When starting the setup.exe I'm not prompted for privilege elevation. The installer will just start and suggest to install to Program Files (x86) which is good. After clicking next the installer runs and finished with a success message. Which is basically a lie because it did not successfully install. Instead it puts the apps exe directly to C:\.

How can I make the installer ask for admin privileges. Or do I have to rely on my customer to right click the setup and select "Run as Admin" which is very error prone?

**Clarifications about my setup**:

- In the File System view of the setup project I added (among other things) "Primary Output from project01 (Active)" and "Build Outputs from project01 (Active) to "Application Folder". I also added a shortcut to "Primary Output" into "User's Programs Menu\CompanyName\ProgramName".
- In the Registry View I added an entry to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT because I need to register an url handler.

I also modified the setup's settings: I set InstallAllUsers to True because it is supposed to do so.

When I build and start the setup.exe by double clicking (or by selecting Install from the project's context menu) I always get the same result: The installer runs without asking for admin privileges, ask for an install location (which I leave at the default C:\Program Files(x86)\Company\ProgramName) and then procedes after clicking Next. As a result, the exe is put directly in C:\ and the shortcut created of course points into Nirvana.

If I run the setup.exe manually as Administrator things work fine. But this cannot seriously be the way to go.

So how can I tell the setup to always run as Admin?

Comment: First of all, you should fix your installer to write files into Program Files rather than C:. Is UAC turned on? Is root of C: writable by limited users?

Comment: As I stated the installer works fine (and installs to Program Files) when manually started as administrator. UAC is turned on, of course. And no, C:\ is not writeable which is standard AFAIK but still the MSI puts the files there if started with low rights.

Comment: That's impossible. An installation process cannot write in C:\ without elevation or appropriate permissions set on C:\. So either your package is being elevated in some way, or C:\ has permissions which gives everyone full access.

Comment: @CosminPirvu The normative power of facts beats your statement. It is happening. On my machine. More then once. I gave up.

Comment: @Cosmin The default permissions do not allow creating files in the root but allow creating folders. This, kind of, explains why installer can write files there without elevating. I suppose in your case a custom action or something fails and INSTALLLOCATION is set to C:\. I'd suggest running install with verbose logging: both non-elevated and elevated, and compare the logs. Magic happens but there's _always_ a logical explanation to magic (*almost always).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a perfectly valid question, is a real problem, and has an actual explanation.

I recently ran across this problem.  In my case, the cause is that the  [`AlwaysInstallElevated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) policy was set on the computer through GPO.  The policy was set to 1 in the per-machine policy and 0 in the per-user policy.  These policies can be manually set to reproduce the effect it has on MSI installers

Using `msexec /log install.log /i Deploy.msi`, I had a setup log and there were strings in it like this:

```
MSI (s) (A4:8C) [13:00:42:885]: Ignoring disallowed property TARGETDIR
MSI (s) (A4:8C) [13:00:42:885]: Ignoring disallowed property VSDNETURLMSG
MSI (s) (A4:8C) [13:00:42:885]: Ignoring disallowed property VSDNETMSG
```

It seems that Visual Studio does not set the [`SecureCustomProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the MSI correctly and post processing of some sort is needed.  I think that moving to [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) may be a better long term solution instead.

A [blog post on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2011/12/21/msi-built-on-visual-studio-installs-into-quot-c-quot-instead-of-quot-c-program-files-quot.aspx) is what I found that helped me find the root cause to this problem.

Comment: No idea why this answer was downrated, mate. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the same issue as you, and have found a good enough solution for it. So it might work for you too. The solution is documented here:

[VS2010 Setup Project - Run As Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496746/vs2010-setup-project-run-as-administrator)

I will re-iterate the solution briefly here. Basically, you need to manually edit the setup project file (.vdproj) and the following property to TRUE:

```
"MsiBootstrapper"
{
    ...
    "RequiresElevation" = "11:TRUE"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When starting the setup.exe I'm not prompted for privilege elevation.

This is the normal behavior. The boostrapper doesn't need elevation.

> Which is basically a lie because it did not successfully install.
>   Instead it puts the apps exe directly to C:.

So it did install your application, but in the wrong location. This is not related to elevation. In the File System editor in your setup project where did you add your application files? Did you add them in "Application Folder"?

> How can I make the installer ask for admin privileges.

A MSI package installed for all users automatically prompts for elevation when clicking Install button. If it doesn't elevate automatically and installs in a per-machine location (like C:), the installation fails and nothing is copied on the target machine.

Comment: No, this is not the case here.

Comment: @Christoph No, the installation would have failed if MSI could not installed one of the files. You can try to run the installation with verbose logging to see what's happening.

Comment: @Alexey Let me tell you this: I'm a fully trained professional software developer with several years of expertise. I never encountered this kind of strange behavior so far but this keeps happening on two different machines. I have no effing idea why the installer is fragged up like this. I even built an new Setup project using the VS2010 Wizard... and still the same result. I decided to keep is as it is and ask my customers to run the installer manually as Admministrator.